# 1st LED turn ON when 1st button is pressed and other LEDs remaining OFF

Tags: led, button

I have 2 LEDs and 2 buttons. What I want to code is when first button pressed the 1st LED turn on (stay on for 5 seconds) and 2nd LED remain off, and same if 2nd button pressed the 2nd LED turn on and 1st LED remain off. I want the processing reset after 5 seconds.
Here is my work, what it does now is 1st LED turn on when I press 1st button, but the 2nd button and 2nd LED still can press and light up right after. I want the 2nd button deactivate when 1st button pressed for 5 seconds.
Please give me basic program because I am new to this.

```
int pinButton_1 = 8; //the pin where we connect the button
int pinButton_2 = 9;
int LED_1 = 1; //the pin we connect the LED
int LED_2 = 2;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pinButton_1, INPUT); //set the button pin as INPUT
  pinMode(pinButton_2, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_1, OUTPUT); //set the LED pin as OUTPUT
  pinMode(LED_2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int stateButton_1 = digitalRead(pinButton_1); //read the state of the button
  int stateButton_2 = digitalRead(pinButton_2); //read the state of the button
  if(stateButton_1 == 1) { //if is pressed
     digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH); //LED_1 on
     digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW); //LED_2 off
     delay(50);
  }
     if (stateButton_2 == 1) {
      digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
      delay(50);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have not implemented a stay on time of 5seconds `delay(5000);` but only 50ms `delay(50);`.

Second, you are not really switching of your LED's if no further button is pressed.

Change your `loop()` to the following, I guess this will help you to start your next steps into getting familiar with your code:

```
    void loop() {
      int stateButton_1 = digitalRead(pinButton_1); //read the state of the Button_1
      if(stateButton_1 == 1) {      //if Button_1 is pressed
         digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH); //LED_1 on
         digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW);  //LED_2 off
         delay(5000);
      }
      digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW); //Switch off LED_1

      int stateButton_2 = digitalRead(pinButton_2); //read the state of the button 2
      if (stateButton_2 == 1) {
         digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
         digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
         delay(5000);
      }
      digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW); //Switch off LED_2
    }
```

**Hint:** Using `delay()` is often not a good construct, better to do it with `millis()`, but this means some more changes. For the start in your case `delay()` will do, but check out what here in different Questions/answers is already written about `delay()` vs. `millis()`

Comment: thank you for your help, I really appreciated